# Issues with a leftbar

Tags: html, css, gradient

I was working with a leftbar for my website. Basically the leftbar comprises of three `div` elements with `id="profile"`.
Also I have floated the `child div` elements towards left.

The issues I am facing:

I analysed the problem with firebug in mozilla firefox, the width of each is equal to the parent element but I don't know how.

Secondly the height of the `child div` elements is not equal to the parent elements. I tried setting `height` of the `div` elements to be `100%` or `34px`, this doesn't solves the problem.

Thirdly the I have added the gradient as a background for the leftbar but the background appears as some solid colour. I have added vendor prefixed prior to the normal gradient brackground. But I really don't know why this happens.

I am adding a jsbin demo for [**this**](http://jsbin.com/ivuqon/2/edit) example

Comment: First of all give **different id** to each of the div element. Same ID to more than one is invalid HTML.

Comment: The CSS gradient syntax needs the prefixes to work. Since older browsers do not support this syntax at all you should first define a fallback rule and after that you set the different vendor variants.

Comment: I have the latest version of both Mozilla and Google Chrome. This should work, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS Syntax for firefox has to be changed to this:

```
-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(213,213,213) 0%, rgb(237,237,237), rgb(213,213,213) 100%);
```

The height is just set to the image container, not the leftbar, set the leftbar to height 34 (and/ or use line-height to center it vertically):

```
.leftbar{
  widh:70%;
  color:#000;
  font-family:Calibri;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:700;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  height:34px;
  line-height:34px;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: the `image` doesn't display now.

Comment: @SumitGera I can't see your images in the example, but are you sure they fit the size of the .image container? Did you add the float left to .leftbar -> otherwise the .image is below the leftbar and you can't see it (because the text doen't fit the size of 26%).

Comment: i meant the `div` elements with `class="image"`. Setting a width anything lower than 26% should work, but it isn't.

Comment: @SumitGera I don't know what you mean, I've updated the demo and I can see the Image text as well as the Leftbar text: http://jsbin.com/ivuqon/7/edit

Comment: Yeah I got what you were saying. Thanks.